# »Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.«

Tags: grammatical-number

Gerade fiel in den »tagesthemen« der Satz:

> Eine halbe Million Häuser wurde zerstört.

Nach meinem Sprachgefühl sollte es besser heißen:

> Eine halbe Million Häuser wurden zerstört.

Ich bin mir aber unsicher. Das Wort *eine* lässt zwar darauf schließen, dass Singular hier richtig ist, aber *die Häuser* (im Plural) sind hier doch das Substantiv, oder?

Hier noch Beispiele dazu, die eindeutig sein sollten:

> Eintausend Häuser wurden zerstört.
>   Ein Drittel der Häuser wurde beschädigt.
>   Eines der Häuser wurde zerstört.

Und hier weitere Beispiele aus der Presse, bei denen ich mir unsicher bin:

> Ein Dutzend Häuser standen in Flammen.
>   Ein Dutzend Häuser verschwindet.

Welche Variante ist richtig oder sind sogar beide Schreibweisen korrekt?

Comment: Ähnlich (auf Englisch): http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6643/use-plural-or-singular-to-refer-to-a-menge-of-something

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Zu dieser Frage gibt es eine sehr gute Antwort auf [grammatikfragen.de](https://grammatikfragen.de/showthread.php?206-Heisst-es-Eine-Million-Deutsche-wei%EF%BF%BD-nicht-ODER-Eine-Million-Deutsche-wissen-nicht).

Hier die wichtigsten Punkte:

- Es gibt eine Kongruenzregel, die besagt, dass Subjekt und Prädikat in Einklang sein müssen.
- Der Numerus wird vom Kern bestimmt, nicht von der [partitiven Apposition](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Satz/Satzgliedbau/Nomen/Apposition.html#Anchor-Partitive-33869).
- Der Kern ist *Eine halbe Million*, welche den Singular verlangt. (Vgl. "Ein halbes Haus" ist offensichtlich Singular.)

Trotzdem wird der Plural auch zugelassen. Die genannten Gründe sind:

- Million bezeichnet 'sehr viel' und der Plural entspricht dann einer *semantischen Kongruenz* (im Gegensatz zu der zuvor beschriebenen *grammatischen Kongruenz*).
- Die meisten tendieren dazu das Wort *Häuser* als Kern aufzufassen, und *eine halbe Million* nur als Zahlenangabe.

Was in deinem Beispiel keinen Einfluss nimmt, aber im genannten Beispiel im verlinkten Thread, und auch von Emanuel in einem Kommentar angesprochen, liegt noch eine starke Tendenz vor, bei Personen/Menschen, den Plural zu verwenden.

Das Ganze wird beispielsweise auch von canoo.net bestätigt. Im Artikel [Kongruenz zwischen Subjekt und Verb: Problemfälle beim Numerus](http://canoonet.eu/services/OnlineGrammar/Wort/Verb/Numerus-Person/ProblemNum.html#Anchor-Mengenangabe-49575) heißt es:

> Wenn die Mengenangabe im Singular und das ihr folgende Nomen im Plural stehen, kann das Verb im Singular oder im Plural stehen. Steht es im Singular, richtet es sich nach dem grammatikalischen Subjekt. Steht es im Plural richtet es sich sinngemäß nach dem inhaltlichen Subjekt.

Bei den dort gelisteten Beispielen wird auch wieder ersichtbar, dass bei Personen der Plural eher verwendet wird.

Fazit:
Beides ist akzeptabel. Wer's sehr streng nimmt, akzeptiert nur den Singular.

Answer (score 12):

Der grammatische Numerus richtet sich nicht immer nach der tatsächlichen Anzahl, sondern folgt häufig der Existenz des Zahlwortes »eins« bzw. dessen Flexionen. Dabei wird auch der unbestimmte Artikel »ein« wie das Zahlwort interpretiert:

> 1. **Eine** Million Häuser **wurde** zerstört.
> 2. **Eine** Million Häuser **wurden** zerstört.
> 3. **Zwei** Millionen Häuser **wurden** zerstört.

Im ersten Fall ist die Einzahl möglich, weil es sich um *ein* Ding handelt, wobei dieses eine Ding eine Gruppe von einer Million Häusern ist.

Im zweiten Fall wird der Satz so interpretiert, dass es sich um mehrere Dinge (nämlich um eine Million Dinge) handelt, wobei jedes Ding ein einzelnes Haus ist.

Im dritten Fall ist es egal, ob man zwei Häuser-Gruppen zu je einer Million Häuser betrachtet, oder zwei Millionen einzelne Häuser. Das Resultat ist immer die Mehrzahl.

Bleiben wir bei der ersten Interpretation. Zur besonderen Kennzeichnung setze ich das, was gezählt wird, in Klammern:

> 1. **Eine** (Million Häuser) **wurde** zerstört.
> 2. **Eine** (Torte) **wurde** zerstört.
> 3. **Eine** (süße Torte) **wurde** zerstört.
> 4. **Eine** (halbe Torte) **wurde** zerstört.
> 5. **Eine** (halbe Million Häuser) **wurde** zerstört.

In 2 habe ich die Gruppe von einer Million Häusern durch eine einzelne Torte ersetzt.

In 3 habe ich der Torte ein Attribut hinzugefügt, dass die Torte näher beschreibt.

In 4 habe ich ein anderes Attribut verwendet. Grammatisch bleibt die Torte in der Einzahl (die einzige Alternative währe die Mehrzahl, sie kommt hier aber nicht in Frage), obwohl es sich nicht mehr um *eine* (ganze) Torte handelt.

In 5 wird aus der Torte wieder die Million-Häuser-Gruppe, und so wird erkennbar, dass man auch eine halbe Million mit der Einzahl behandeln kann.

Wenn man die Häuser hinter der Million weglässt, ist nur mehr die Einzahl möglich:

> richtig: Eine Million **wurde** zerstört.
>   falsch: Eine Million **wurden** zerstört.

Hier hat die Million auf keinen Fall mehr die Funktion eines Zähl-Wortes, denn das, was damit gezählt werden könnte, ist im Satz gar nicht vorhanden. Stattdessen ist die Million selbst das (eine) Objekt, das gezählt wird.

Daher auch:

> Ein Drittel ist reif.
>   Ein Drittel der Tomaten ist reif.
>   Ein Drittel der Häuser wurde beschädigt.

Weder die Tomaten noch die Häuser werden gezählt (sie geben nur an, wessen Drittel gemeint ist). Gezählt werden die Drittel, und weil es davon in jedem Satz nur eines gibt, muss die Einzahl verwendet werden.

Aber:

> Einhundert Menschen **sind** im Saal.
>   Eintausend Häuser **wurden** zerstört.

*Einhundert* und *eintausend* sind ganz normale Zahlwörter, so wie auch *zwei* oder *siebenundvierzig*, und verlangen daher die Mehrzahl.

Und für das Dutzend gilt dasselbe wie für Million:

> Ein Dutzend Eier ist faul.
>   Ein Dutzend Eier sind faul.

Beide Varianten sind richtig.

Comment: Ein Sonderfall ist "Eine Million Menschen sind" da klingt "ist" für mich falsch. Generell ist es bei einer Million Menschen etwas unschärfer.