# plural subject and singular predicate nominative with linking verb sein

Tags: grammar-identification

My book says, If the verb sein is followed by a noun in the plural, the verb has a plural ending even if the subject is singular.

> ex. Es sind Störche.

My question is, What if the subject is in a plural form and predicate nominative is in a singular form, then in which form (singular or plural) will the verb be? I am asking this question out of my curiosity though I am not sure if such sentence form exist or not.

Comment: Related: https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/24766/eine-halbe-million-h%c3%a4user-wurde-zerst%c3%b6rt

Answer (score 3):

If the subject is plural and the predicate is singular then *sein* is in the plural

> Diese Sachen sind Abfall
>   Fünf Tore sind ein gutes Ergebnis
>   Batman und Robin sind das dynamische Duo

You find this often if the predicate is a collective noun

Comment: Sätze enden mit einem Punkt.

Answer (score 3):

PiedPiper's answer is right, but your book is a bit short on explanations, it seems. *Sein* isn't a special case, all *copula* verbs follow that rule. For example:

> Diese Sachen bleiben Abfall.
>
> 12 Stück heißen ein Dutzend.
>
> Fünf Tore bleiben ein gutes Ergebnis.
>
> Die Bayern gelten als Ausnahmemannschaft.
>
> Aber die Dortmunder werden Meister.